# Data for factory coming too late–Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, http

I had similar code to this working before and for some reason, this one chunk is not.  It's a simple idea; call the function, it calls an `$http`-based factory to get data and return an array of that data.  First is the factory:

```
app.factory('getSensors', ['data', function (data) {
  return { get : function() {
      data.get('sensors').then(function (results) {
        var sensors = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < results.sensors.length; i++) {
          sensors.push({
            'id'        : Number(results.sensors[i][0]),
            'name'      : results.sensors[i][1],
            'type'      : results.sensors[i][2],
            'device'    : results.sensors[i][3],
            'unit'      : results.sensors[i][4],
            'parent'    : Number(results.sensors[i][5]),
            'latitude'  : Number(results.sensors[i][6]),
            'longitude' : Number(results.sensors[i][7])
          });
        }

        return sensors;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Which uses the following `data` service:

```
app.factory('data', ['$http', function ($http) {
  var serviceBase = '/api/';
  var obj = {};

  obj.get = function (q) {
    return $http.get(serviceBase + q).then(function (results) {
      return results.data;
    });
  };

  return obj;
}]);
```

And for the call to the factory, I've tried `getSensors`, `getSensors.get`, and `getSensors.get()`, even though I know some of those are wrong.  I have also tried not wrapping this code in a function, using a function defined above the return, and returned the array in no object (how it is working in my other function, even though I don't think it is best practice, it's just simpler).  I've even swapped the `for` loop for a `forEach`.

Basically, the returned value from the `getSensors` factory always happens before the `$http` call completes from my use of console debugging, even if the code is in the callback function and after that loop.  I am at a loss as to how this is possible after spending 2 hours looking at it and rewriting this code.  I maybe am simply missing something obvious or am violating some aspect of Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical part you are missing is to `return` the promise created by the `.then()` in your `getSensors.get()` method:

```
app.factory('getSensors', ['data', function (data) {
  return { get : function() {
      return data.get('sensors').then(function (results) {
        var sensors = [];

        /* for loop (same as before) goes here */

        return sensors;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Then to use it, just inject the `getSensors` service as a dependency, and call

```
getSensors.get().then(function (sensors) { 
    /* do something with sensors array */ 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I suppose you just always need to wait and use `.then()` for anything with `$http`...

Comment: Yep - `$http` just returns a promise, and everything with promises is asynchronous and needs to be accessed with `.then()`. I have changed to making many, many functions return promises if there is ever a chance they need to do something asynchronously. Btw, I make this kind of mistake all the time - forgetting to return the promise from a function. You are not the only one.